# Does final variables occupy memory on a per-instance basis?

Tags: java, class, heap-memory, final, instance-variables

I have read other question-answers regarding final instance variables and  i came to knew that ***non-static final instance variables are created in heap for every instance of the class*** but in *java -the complete reference by herbert schildt* it is said that :

> Variables declared as final do not occupy memory on a per-instance basis .thus, a final variable is essentially a constant

Which is correct?

Comment: A final instance variable does take up memory. It can be different for every instance, and that value must be stored somewhere. The information in the quote is wrong.

Comment: Thanks! Is book's line really wrong? Is there is any other way to justify that it is correct, if any? just curious!

Comment: [The book](http://iiti.ac.in/people/~tanimad/JavaTheCompleteReference.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A2577%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C-27%2C670%2Cnull%5D) seems to be assuming that a final variable must be a compile-time constant. It appears to be a mistake. It also says "This means that you must initialize a
final variable when it is declared." which is also not necessarily true, in particular for final instance variables that can be assigned in the constructor.

Comment: Can this assumption be made by the compiler if final variables are initialized at their declaration itself and allocate memory to it only one time because obviously every instance created will have the same value for that final variable.is compiler  smart enough to do this kind of optimization? and whether it is allowed in some version of java or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first statement is correct ... though limited to `final` fields of instances.

The second statement is incorrect.

A `final` variable will occupy memory *somewhere* at runtime.  However where that memory is depends on the kind of variable that you declare as `final`.

- If the variable is a local variable or a method's formal argument variable, then the memory cell will be on the stack.
- If the variable is a non-static field, then the memory cell will be part of an object, and will be in the heap.
- If the variable is a static field, then the location of the memory cell will be implementation dependent.  (It could be in the heap, or it could be somewhere else.)

It should be noted that some (but not all!) kinds of `static final` fields are compile constants, and their values are effectively inlined by the compiler.  But even when that happens, there will still be an actual field that occupies a memory cell at runtime, and the contents of that memory cell can be accessed reflectively.

(Indeed, you can even modify a `final` field reflectively.  When you do that, the behavior is not specified by the JVM spec, and can be rather surprising in some cases.)

---

> Does final variables occupy memory on a per-instance basis?

No, because:

- static variables don't "occupy memory on a per-instance" whether or not they are `final`.
- local variables and parameters can be `final` too, and they don't  "occupy memory on a per-instance"

---

> Can this assumption be made by the compiler if `final` variables are initialized at their declaration itself and allocate memory to it only one time because obviously every instance created will have the same value for that final variable.   Is compiler smart enough to do this kind of optimization?

Consider this

```
public class Test
    public static test(final int val) {
        System.out.println(val);
    }
}
```

Now `val` is `final`, but its value depends on how you call `test` method.  That is not known at (`javac`) compile time, and typically it is not known to the JIT compiler either.  Indeed, assuming that `test` is called with different parameters, you can't directly optimize away the `val` memory cell.

The same applies to every case apart from `static final` variables that qualify as compile-time constants (as per the JLS definition).

It is theoretically possible that the JIT compiler could see that `Test.test` is only ever called with the same constant value, and inline that value into the native code so that no memory cell is needed.  However, that optimization has minimal performance benefit, and is unlikely to be applicable in real-life code.  So I doubt that it is *worth* implementing it.

(It is more likely for `val` to be optimized away due to inlining the body of `test` into its call site.  That is a more general optimization an is definitely worthwhile.  That may then allow the peephole optimizer to deduce that `val` is not needed in the inlined code.)